# Google spreadsheet "Cannot call method "getRange" of null"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to generate a unique ID in column A if column B has changed in every row from the 6th. It would be enough to use a number from 1 to X as ID but it should no change after moving de row. Yet I'm getting an error continuously "Cannot call method "getRange" of null."

```
function onEdit() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ScriptTest');
 var column0 = sheet.getRange(6, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-6, 1);
 var oValues = column0.getValues();

 if (oValues[sheet.getLastRow()][0] == '') {
   sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 1).setValue(ContentService.createTextOutput(sheet.getLastRow()-6));
 }  
}
```

Comment: is script test the name of the tab or of the document? You need to provide the name of the current worksheet, not the document in getSheetByName().

Comment: It's the name of the tab which is the current worksheet as well. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: That's odd. can you put a breakpoint on the line where you are declaring column0, and then run the function in debug mode please? Does it have sheet  as an Object with an id in brackets? Are you sure the tab name is ScriptTest, not Scripttest or Script Test or scriptTest?

Comment: Well I triple checked the tab name and it was misspelled.. Thanks for you help! If you'd write an answer I'll give the check mark (:

Comment: Glad it's working now, i posted an answer elaborating on the issue a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have errors with working with sheet objects like here you can easily identify the source by the kind of missing value it's pulling from.

`undefined` is undefined, meaning the variable for the sheet was never given a value or has been set to undefined.

the variable is set to `null` when you are trying to get a tab by a name that doesn't exist, as **is the case here**.

Anything else probably means you are accessing the wrong variable.

Comment: Just started to use google app script thanks for helping to improve my skills!