# Copy columns to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy specific columns from one sheet to another. I know I am a noob, but I have tried searching a lot for the answer.

as you can see, I am trying to copy the values from specific columns (in reality there is more), and then copy them to another spreadsheet in an order I control.

It's my own take on it. First, I am looping through the columns A, C, D, F, taking the values one by one, and for each one, I wish to paste them to the otherspreadsheet looping through the columns A, B, C, D as the target. But it gives me an error 
"TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 11, file "test")"

```
function copySheet() { 
 var sourceSheet  =
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("source");`
 var destSheet  = 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("target");`

 var columns_to_be_copied = [1, 3, 4, 6];
 var columns_to_be_pasted = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 var data = []
 for (i = 0; i < columns_to_be_copied.length; i++) {
  var sourcerange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, columns_to_be_copied[i], 
  sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  for (t = 0; t < columns_to_be_copied.length; i++) {
   var targetrange = destSheet.getRange(2, columns_to_be_pasted[t], 
   destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
   targetrange.setValues(sourcerange);    
  }
 }
}
```

Also, I was wondering if anyone know of any way where I can getRange from A:AD (example) where the values in column D, which is formatted as datetime, is before =today()-90? I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere. Do anyone have a reference for this question?

Comment: Related: [Google spreadsheet “Cannot call method ”getRange“ of null”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33208851/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just copying data, you don't need to get the values. You can copy a range directly from one sheet to another. This modified function accomplishes your first goal of copying specific columns from a source into sequential columns in a destination sheet.

```js
function copySheet() { 
 var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet7");
 var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet8");

 var columns_to_be_copied = [1, 3, 4, 6];

 for (var i = 0; i < columns_to_be_copied.length; i++) {
  var sourcerange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, columns_to_be_copied[i], sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1)
  sourcerange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(1,(i+1)))
 }
}
```

As to your second question, you can use a helper function to check dates:

```js
  // count back n days
  Date.prototype.modDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
    return date;
  }
```

In your function, you would use something like (untested):

```js
var today = new Date()
var future = today.modDays(90)
```

Comment: Will this work copying from one spreadsheet to another? I think that's what the person who asked the question wrote. This solution doesn't work for me when copying from one spreadsheet to another but it works between sheets of the same spreadsheet.

Comment: @DanCue as written, no. But his code sample was for two sheets in the same Spreadsheet. To get it to work between sheets, change line 3 to `destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('someId').getSheetByName('remoteDestSheet');`. Make sure you have edit access to the destination sheet.

Comment: Ok. That's what I figured. I ended up going the set values route, though.