# TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 25, file "Code")

Tags: dictionary, google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization, google-fusion-tables

Below is the code I'm getting the cannot call method error on:
I'm trying to sync [this fusion table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4BCp0l4NLn4A05cdn_EF00VkaNQRhfX6pwkQL_yMH4/edit#gid=0):

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|   ID   |       NAME      |                    ADDRESS                       |
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| BAKLAR | Larry Baker     | 6460 West Dry Creek, Belgrade, MT                |
| STOJEN | Jennifer Stoner | 8580 Highline Rd., Manhattan, MT                 |
| FATJAS | Jason Fatouros  | 857 West Ddryy Creek, Belgrade, MT               |
| DILMIC | Michael Dilbeck | 8150 Theisen Belgrade, MT                        |
| RYDGER | Gerald Ryder    | 14825 SPANISH BREAKS TRAIL, GALLATIN GATEWAY, MT |
| Work   | MEA             | 550 WEST MADISON, BELGRADE, MT                   |
+--------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

To this map:
https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1JPYFxHbuvM8yFeRvsNCbFoy9Hq38-bQqw8lFcTG2&pli=1#map:id=3

When I run the function I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 25, file "Code")

```
/**
 * AppsScript script to run in a Google Spreadsheet that synchronizes its
 * contents with a Fusion Table by replacing all rows.
 */

// Replace with your Fusion Table's ID (from File > About this table)
var TABLE_ID = '1kbKpXrQYnN09k693-LLud6aacZeTojpM2kBOI7GC';

// First row that has data, as opposed to header information
var FIRST_DATA_ROW = 2;

// True means the spreadsheet and table must have the same column count
var REQUIRE_SAME_COLUMNS = true;

/**
 * Replaces all rows in the Fusion Table identified by TABLE_ID with the
 * current sheet's data, starting at FIRST_DATA_ROW.
 */
function sync() {
  var tasks = FusionTables.Task.list(TABLE_ID);
  // Only run if there are no outstanding deletions or schema changes.
  if (tasks.totalItems == 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var wholeSheet = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),
        sheet.getLastColumn());
    var values = wholeSheet.getValues();
    if (values.length > 1) {
      var csvBlob = Utilities.newBlob(convertToCsv_(values),
          'application/octet-stream');
      FusionTables.Table.replaceRows(TABLE_ID, csvBlob,
         { isStrict: REQUIRE_SAME_COLUMNS, startLine: FIRST_DATA_ROW - 1 });
      Logger.log('Replaced ' + values.length + ' rows');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Skipping row replacement because of ' + tasks.totalItems +
        ' active background task(s)');
  }
}


/**
 * Converts the spreadsheet values to a CSV string.
 * @param {Array} data The spreadsheet values.
 * @return {string} The CSV string.
 */
function convertToCsv_(data) {
  // See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section3
  var csv = '';
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var value = data[row][col].toString();
      if (value.indexOf(',') != -1 ||
          value.indexOf('\n') != -1 ||
          value.indexOf('"') != -1) {
        // Double-quote values with commas, double quotes, or newlines
        value = '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
        data[row][col] = value;
      }
    }
    // Join each row's columns and add a carriage return to end of each row
    // except the last
    if (row < data.length - 1) {
      csv += data[row].join(',') + '\r\n';
    }
    else {
      csv += data[row];
    }
  }
  return csv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that error occurs because the script is a standalone script instead of a bounded to spreadsheet script so `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` retuns null instead of a Sheet object.

Related

- [Google spreadsheet "Cannot call method "getRange" of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33208851/1595451)