# Multi-criteria based Email Alert Trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**This is my data:**
[image]

Now, I want to send an email to myself when 2 criteria are fulfilled:

1. "Date" column D is yesterday's date. 
   **AND**
2. "Value" column F -where column D is yesterday- is greater than 0.5.

Based on this criteria, the script should trigger for 20190110 since the value in F is 0.7. However, the script does not trigger since the execution takes too long somehow. Could it be loop related since it is going through so many rows?

This is what I have so far. I would appreciate how to make this actually trigger an email. Thanks!

```
function readCell() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
    var dates = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues(); //date column

    var date = null;
    var dateRow = 0;
    var dateCount = dates.length;

    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    var yesterdayString = yesterday.toDateString();

    for (dateRow; dateRow < dateCount; ++dateCount) {

        date = dates[dateRow];

        if (date instanceof Date) {
            date = date.toDateString();

            if (date === yesterdayString) {
                ++dateRow;
                // To account for zero-based array
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var value = sheet.getRange('F' + dateRow).getValue();

    if (value >= 0.5) {
      var result = 'Result found on: ' + date;
      MailApp.sendEmail('test@gmail.com', 'Alert', result);
    }
};
```

Here is the Stackdriver Error Report
[image]

Comment: When you `View -> Stackdriver Logs`, what do you observe?

Comment: Hi, I just added the logs in the original post. Would you know what is going on?

Comment: @tehhowch. I added the logs to show the error. Did you already see it by chance?

Comment: If there is no worksheet with the exact name `test` in the workbook to which your script project is bound, then that error occurs. You can and must do research on error messages you get, and show how you have attempted to resolve them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google spreadsheet "Cannot call method "getRange" of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208851/google-spreadsheet-cannot-call-method-getrange-of-null)

Comment: Also I believe `date = dates[dateRow];` needs to be `date = dates[dateRow][0];`

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try something like this:

```
function readCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('test');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var yesterday=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()-1);
  var yesterdayString=Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd")
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {//Start at one if you have a header line
    if (isDate(vA[i][3])) {
      var t1=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][3]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd");
      if(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][3]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd")==yesterdayString && Number(vA[i][5])>=0.5) {
        //MailApp.sendEmail('test@gmail.com','Alert', 'Result found on: ' + Number(i+1))
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(i+1);
      }
    }
  }
}

function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

I just tested this with this data.

[image]

The alert showed on line 11. Which is yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, Cooper. One question, for the va[i][3] you call out, do you mean to refer to the 3rd column in the Google sheet which is the Date? Because the Date column is in column D which is the 4th column. In this case, shall I adjust the array parameter? Anyhow, I tried both va[] array values (the one you initially posted and the adjusted ones I just suggested) but I still do not get an email alert. So frustrating :(

Comment: vA[i][3] is column 4 because arrays start at zero.  Your question specifies the date in Column D which is column4.

Comment: got it. so then, give va[3] and va[5], I still do not get any email. when i debug, it does not show any errors.

Comment: By the way, it's not va[3],va[5] it's vA[i][3], vA[i][5]. It's a 2d array or Object[][]

Comment: Cooper, I meant va[i][3] and va[i][5]. I mistyped. sorry. As far as the current code goes, it is the same you initially posted. I only changed the email address to my actual one.

Comment: I set up some dates and values and tested the above code and it works.  Perhaps there's something amiss with the sendMail method because I commented that out.

Comment: Cooper, I actually uncommented that line and changed it to my email. This is so strange. The only other thing is that column D and column E are coming daily through an API while column F is just a calculation I added using D and E. Neverthless, I do not think that should be an issue for the script. Would you think of anything on that end which would prevent the script to trigger?

Comment: As I said it's working on my end.  I think the only option is to single step through it and figure out what's going on.